# Front dérailleur does not shift into largest chainring

Tags: derailleur, shifter, shifting

I have a Shimano ST-EF60-8R shifter with a Shimano FD3303 front derailleur - it does not go into 3rd gear which is the largest; it feels like the wire is going to pop. I just bought the bike, a Trek 1000, which runs great otherwise.

I've tried adjusting according to YouTube videos (not hard at all) but I can't seem to get the adjustment to be able to shift into all 3 gears. Is it a mismatch?

Comment: Can you shift to the largest cog by pulling on the cable?  Did the videos show you how to adjust the limit screws on the derailer?

Comment: Which things from videos did you do? Did you set the cable tension?

Comment: Sounds like you need to unwind your H limit screw to allow the cable to move more. Front derailleurs are actually quite complicated to set up if it's the first time you've done it because there are quite a lot of variables at play. Once set though they are more forgiving and need much less ongoing adjustment

Comment: The ST-EF60 shifter is a from Shimano's lowest level 3x8 Tourney line, and nominally for a mountain bike or hybrid. The FD-3300 derailleur is from the better quality Sora 3x9 road bike line. This is a very odd mix that raises all kinds of questions. Can you clarify what bike model you have? When I Googled for info about a Trek 1000 I found info for [a drop bar road bike](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/11110/) with Sora components. I wonder if you have one of these that someone has put a flat handlebar on?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus don't forget 3300 is 8 speed, before Sora went 9speed

Comment: The listings I find on Bicycle Blue Book show Trek 1000 as a road bike with drop-style handlebars.  The ST-EF60 shifter, however, is for flat handlebars. Can you clear up this discrepancy?

Comment: I'd be checking the cable routing at the derailleur. There is a subtle little leverage tab that the cable has to go over before securing by the pinch bolt. The flat bar shifter situation needs to be examined as well. I doubt there's direct incompatibility cable pull wise but something is hinky

Comment: @Swifty you are right, it’s 8 speed

Comment: My fear is if the flat bar conversion theory is true, the bike may have incompatible MTB brake levers and road calipers.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus totally, it is a bit of a mis-match. Good catch though, a road bike frame won't take v-brakes of course while the shifters do https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/ev/EV-ST-EF60-2A-2744.pdf I cannot recall if the brake levers feature a conversion switch, which would be worth checking

Comment: @Jeff makes a great point about the cable fixing. jflex2, you could [edit] photos of the derailleur fixing bolt area into the question, that would be a big help